# Where would the commas go in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

A man so powerful he could crush stones in his hands approached me.

I'm not sure, but I'm guessing after "powerful" and maybe "hands"?

Answer (score 3):

You would place the commas so that "so powerful he could crush stones in his hands" becomes secondary to the main sentence "A man approached me.":

> A man, so powerful he could crush stones in his hands, approached me.